# NSTextView and text baloons (like in Mail app)

Tags: cocoa

I'm wondering how create such baloons in NSTextView, as in send mail window. I found one way of doing this, but I want user delete all baloon in one click (or transfer it to another location) ?

Seems that it NSTextAttachment, but I not sure really.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple single-line field like in the screenshot, that would be an [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you want to do it in a big NSTextView, like Xcode autocomplete, then you'll have to create it from scratch. (Probably with NSTextAttachment + NSAttributedString)